# How to check case owner is active or not

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, case, user

I need to check whether the case owner is active or not? in trigger

**Code:**

```
 for(Case cs : trigger.new){
        system.debug('hello owner'+cs.owner);//returning null
        system.debug('hello active'+cs.owner.isactive);// always returning false
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `Case.Owner` is polymorphic (User v Queue), you will need a custom formula field on Case

```
Is_Owner_Active__c
```

defined as Checkbox and value:

`Owner:User.IsActive || ISPICKVAL(Owner:Queue.Type,'Queue')`

Then you can interrogate that in the Trigger.new

```
cs.Is_Owner_Active__c
```

without having to do any queries

> Technical Note:
>
> There is a special datatype called [Name](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_name.htm) that is relevant with
>   Polymorphic lookup relationships (such as fields Task.WhoId,
>   Task.WhatId, or Case/Lead.OwnerId). While `cs.owner.IsActive` is
>   referenceable, it only has a value if the owner is a User.

Comment: To be pedantic, IsActive *is* known, see the [Name](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_name.htm) data type.

Comment: @sfdcfox - -hmm, I had to do the above in an org for the very issue raised by OP - are you saying that the solution is incorrect or the first line is inaccurate

Comment: It's just the first paragraph that's inaccurate. The formula method is itself quite useful.

Comment: @sfdcfox -- fixed and thanks -- not sure I agree with the duplicate OP labeling though as my solution doesn't require any queries for this narrow use case and the dup answers all involve queries

Comment: You can use the formula technique on other types of lookup fields, though most people don't, since formulas tend to suck up a bit of performance. Technically, we should have a global Q&A that ties all of these questions under a single umbrella; I could see this answer and one of the others (using a Map and a query) as the two solutions to the problem, since either of them work.

Comment: That said, I see your point, though, there's something unusual here: why is IsActive "false" instead of "null" or "true"? If you provided that information, I think it would be a significantly different theme than the other questions. Or maybe it'll get reopened anyways. I actually kind of closed this question 19 seconds before your answer posted (according to the time stamps?). If you think it's worth reopening, I think I can undo it.